# VSTS 2017: How to deploy task on MacOSX test agent?

Tags: macos, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I followed the instructions on [Deploy Visual Studio Test Agent Task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/DeployVisualStudioTestAgent/README.md) to deploy my job on Mac OSX agents.

My Mac OSX is 10.12, PowerShell is 6.0 and I have already installed .NET Core on Mac and also updated the openSSL followed by instructions.
My VSTS is: https://vivicai.visualstudio.com

Following command is for Windows, what’s the equivalent for Mac OSX?

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=yes
```

After running following command in Mac OSX, it always shows the error, 
[image]

what can I do to fix the error? Thank you very much.

```
ConfigureWinRM.ps1 {FQDN} https
```

Comment: Please add relevant lines of the error message to the post instead of showing it in image.

Comment: You should provide link of the title which you were referring. Else no one gets the idea which document you were talking about. I have updated it with github link. If it is not the same please edit it and update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported for Mac OSX.

[Test: Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/visual-studio-test-agent-deployment)

> Demands and prerequisites
>
> This task requires the target computer to have:
>
> ```
>   Windows 7 Service Pack 1 or Windows 2008 R2 Service Pack 2 or higher
>
>   .NET 4.5 or higher
>
>   PSRemoting enabled by running the Enable-PSRemoting PowerShell script
> ```

[Install and configure test agents](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/lab-management/test-machines/install-configure-test-agents)

> Requirements
>
> Windows 10
>
> Windows 8, Windows 8.1
>
> Windows 7 Service Pack 1
>
> Windows XP Service Pack 3
>
> Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2
>
> Windows Server 2008 Release 2, Service Pack 1

Comment: Thank you very much for your updates. And I have another question, if I want to deploy a distributed test for Xamarin.iOS, the task will run on Windows agent, not Mac OSX agent?

Comment: @caivivi Yes, you can consider Xamarin test step/task (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/xamarin-test-cloud)